# jquery 1.12.4 Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using jQuery1.12.4 and it is showing `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error when I make a post request but I am not looping it nor am I selecting a lot of values.

javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {    
    $('#update-cart-btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked')

        let prodId = $('#product-id').val();
        let prodQuantity = $('#quantity-number');

        $.post('/api/shop/cart/add', {
            itemId:prodId,
            itemQuantity:prodQuantity
        }, function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        })
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? the `console.log('clicked')` is only getting called once

Comment: isn't it `$('#quantity-number').val();`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be because of

```
$('#quantity-number');
```

It should be

```
$('#quantity-number').val();
```

Comment: I had an un-declared variable in javascript, which was being sent in ajax, (declaring + initializing) it removed the problem.
Got idea from your ans. Thankks.